# Create grid of threads in OpenCL

Tags: concurrency, opencl

I wrote a kernel for OpenCL where I initialise all the elements of a 3D array to -> i*i*i + j*j*j. I'm now having problems in creating a grid of threads to do the initialisation of the elements (concurrently). I know that the code that I have now only uses 3 threads, how can I expand on that?

Please help. I'm new to OpenCL, so any suggestion or explanation might be handy. Thanks!

This is code:

```
_kernel void initialize (
int X;
int Y;
int Z;
_global float*A) {

// Get global position in X direction
int dirX = get_global_id(0);
// Get global position in Y direction
int dirY = get_global_id(1);
// Get global position in Z direction
int dirZ = get_global_id(2);

int A[2000][100][4];
int i,j,k;
for (i=0;i<2000;i++)
{
    for (j=0;j<100;j++)
    {
        for (k=0;k<4;k++)
        {
            A[dirX*X+i][dirY*Y+j][dirZ*Z+k] = i*i*i + j*j*j;
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: It looks like this code passes A in as a __global float*, then redeclares it as an int array, which is inherently private.  Is that intentional?

Comment: Hi, aside from hiding the 'A' variable as boiler96 has highlighted, why do you say that you only use 3 threads? Your work group size has 3 dimensions (X, Y and Z) so I suspect you are creating many more than 3 threads (work items) in your calling code. What size do you want your ultimate output array - 2000x100x4 or a multiple of these dimensions?

Comment: @boiler96 I think that's a mistake I made, it should be an array. Can you help with correcting this?

Comment: @JamesBeilby my ultimate output array should be 2000x100x4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You create the buffer to store your output 'A' in the *calling* (host) code. This is passed to your kernel as a pointer, which is correct in your function definition above. However you don't need to declare it again inside your kernel function, so remove the line `int A[2000][100][4];`.
- You can simplify the code greatly. Using the 3D global ID to indicate the 3D index into the array for each work-item, you could change the loop as follows (assuming that for a given i and j, all elements along Z should have the same value):

  ```
  __kernel void initialize (__global float* A) {
    // cast required so that kernel compiler knows the array dimensions
    __global float (*a)[2000][100][4] = A;

    // Get global position in X direction
    int i = get_global_id(0);
    // Get global position in Y direction
    int j = get_global_id(1);
    // Get global position in Z direction
    int k = get_global_id(2);

    (*a)[i][j][k] = i*i*i + j*j*j;
  }
  ```

In your calling code you would then create the kernel with a global work-size of 2000x100x4.

- Practically this is a *lot* of work items to schedule, so you would likely get better performance from a global (one-dimensional) work-size of 2000 and a loop inside the kernel, e.g.:

  ```
  __kernel void initialize (__global float* A) {
    // cast required so that kernel compiler knows the array dimensions
    __global float (*a)[2000][100][4] = A;

    // Get global position in X direction
    int i = get_global_id(0);

    for (j=0;j<100;j++) {
      for (k=0;k<4;k++) {
        (*a)[i][j][k] = i*i*i + j*j*j;
      }
    }
  }
  ```

Comment: Just a related question. If "A" is not a defined matrix, how can the compiler know the size of each dimension? I wonder if A[i*100*4+j*4+k] is the correct method to access the matrix.

Comment: The first two bullets are a great answer to the question here, but I disagree with your last bullet. It's better to just write the code as simply as possible, leave the workgroup size undefined, and let the OpenCL SDK deal with preparing optimized code. Unless you are writing with a specific hardware in mind and have already identified  this code as inefficient, I don't think it's a good idea to modify it like this.

Comment: @DarkZeros, +1 good point and I have added a cast to the answer to cater for this. An alternative would be to use a single-dimensional array as you suggest, maybe passing the dimensions as an argument to the kernel.

Comment: @Oak, +1 as it's hard to argue with K.I.S.S. principle, but on the same basis you might ask why use OpenCL at all: an implementation in the host language is probably simpler rather than messing about with buffers and kernels! Since most people are using OpenCL to optimize host code, rather than purely "theoretical" OpenCL, I would say they should always have the implementation in mind, e.g. an appreciation of the scheduler, how much memory is available, where it is and how it is accessed.

Comment: My point is less about simplicity and more about performance: in general, the SDK would do a better job setting workgroup sizes and iterating over work items than you, unless you're customizing to the exact architecture you are targeting. Just assign one work item per logical piece of work, and let the SDK optimize it - for instance, maybe it will choose itself to add these loops you've added, and maybe not.

Comment: @Oak, this only applies if the OpenCL implementation really knows best. Much like optimizing C/C++, simplicity can often provide the best results with more mature compilers, or where the code must be portable across compilers or hardware targets. However at this stage in OpenCL development, the compilers are relatively immature and I think more coaxing and experimentation is required. For example the current NVidia implementation will happily pay the scheduling overhead for many tiny work items, and on that platform adding such loops for large work sizes can often be beneficial.

Comment: Thank you all for the suggestions, especially @JamesBeilby.